# Loop on Widget part

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How to iterate only the widget part of the terraform script and get all the widget in a single dashboard?

```
locals {
  instances = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/sample.csv"))
}
```

// if we use count it will loop this part

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "main" {
  dashboard_name = "my-dashboard" 

  dashboard_body = <<EOF
 { 
   "widgets": [
       {
          "type":"metric",
          "x":0,
          "y":0,
          "width":12,
          "height":6,  

          "properties":{
             "metrics":[ 
              for itr in local.instances.id:

                [
                   "AWS/EC2",
                   "CPUUtilization",
                   "InstanceId",
                   itr   // want this section to fetch the value form excel 
                ]

             ],
             "period":300,
             "stat":"Average",
             "region":"ap-south-1",
             "title":"EC2 Instance CPU ",
             "annotations": {
                "horizontal": [
                      {
                         "label": "Untitled annotation",
                         "value": 2
                     }]}

          }},]}EOF}
```

Comment: i am getting this error Error: Putting dashboard failed: InvalidParameterInput: The dashboard body is invalid, there are 4 validation errors:
[
  {
    "dataPath": "/widgets/0",
    "message": "Should be object"
  },
  {
    "dataPath": "/widgets/1",
    "message": "Should be object"
  },
  {
    "dataPath": "/widgets/2",
    "message": "Should be object"
  },
  {
    "dataPath": "/widgets/3",
    "message": "Should be object"
  }
]
 status code: 400, request id: f7fa97fb-a79d-11e9-b42e-a5d1961d71cc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to generate JSON, it's generally better to use `jsonencode` rather than `template_file`, because it can handle the JSON syntax details automatically and thus avoid the need to tweak annoying details of a text template to get the JSON right.

For example:

```
dashboard_body = jsonencode({
  "widgets": [
    "type": "metric",
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "width": 12,
    "height": 6,

    "properties": {
      "metrics": [
        for inst in local.instances : [
          "AWS/EC2",
          "CPUUtilization",
          "InstanceId",
          inst.id,
        ]
      ],
      "period": 300,
      # etc, etc
    },
  ],
})
```

By using `jsonencode` you can use any of Terraform's normal language features and functions to produce your data structure, and leave the `jsonencode` function to turn that into valid JSON syntax at the end.

Comment: @Martin_Atkins can you let me know . how can i loop whole widgets part and use inst.id in the mertics . i tired it writing for immediately after widget but got error   {
    "dataPath": "/widgets/3",
    "message": "Should be object"
  }
]

Comment: Terraform 0.12 supports for loop. It is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use two template_file resources.

sample.csv for test

```
instance_id
i-00001
i-00002
i-00003
```

1. create a template_file resouce for loop,

```tf
data "template_file" "ec2_metric" {
  count    = length(local.instances)
  template = jsonencode([ "AWS/EC2", "CPUUtilization", "InstanceId", element(local.instances.*.instance_id, count.index)])
}
```

2. create a template_file for whole json

```tf
data "template_file" "widgets" {
  template = <<JSON
  { 
   "widgets": [
       {
          "type":"metric",
          "x":0,
          "y":0,
          "width":12,
          "height":6,  

          "properties":{
             "metrics":[ 
               ${join(", \n               ", data.template_file.ec2_metric.*.rendered)}

             ],
             "period":300,
             "stat":"Average",
             "region":"ap-south-1",
             "title":"EC2 Instance CPU ",
             "annotations": {
                "horizontal": [
                      {
                         "label": "Untitled annotation",
                         "value": 2
                     }]}

          }},]}
JSON
}
```

3. using template_file,

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "main" {
  dashboard_name = "my-dashboard" 

  dashboard_body = data.template_file.widgets.rendered
...
}
```

4. Test template_file.widgets

```
output "test" {
  value = data.template_file.widgets.rendered
}
```

result

```
Outputs:

test =   { 
   "widgets": [
       {
          "type":"metric",
          "x":0,
          "y":0,
          "width":12,
          "height":6,  

          "properties":{
             "metrics":[ 
               ["AWS/EC2","CPUUtilization","InstanceId","i-00001"], 
               ["AWS/EC2","CPUUtilization","InstanceId","i-00002"], 
               ["AWS/EC2","CPUUtilization","InstanceId","i-00003"]
             ],
             "period":300,
             "stat":"Average",
             "region":"ap-south-1",
             "title":"EC2 Instance CPU ",
             "annotations": {
                "horizontal": [
                      {
                         "label": "Untitled annotation",
                         "value": 2
                     }]}

          }},]}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @RyanKim ..  i am getting this error   on main.tf line 49, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "main":
  49: resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "main" {

Comment: Note that your json is invalid
you need to change }},]}  to }} ]}

Comment: Thank you Very Much . it worked . you saved my day .    if you could let me know any source to study terraform it would be of great help . i am new to terraform .